# How does this transmission valve "hydraulic computer" work?

Tags: hydraulics, valves, transmission

I just came across this:

[image]

The claim is that it is a kind of analogue computer. But I don't see any moving parts. How does it work?

EDIT: If someone could draw lines on the diagram to illustrate, that would be great.

Comment: Since they mention that it is a valve **body**, moving parts might have been removed before taking this picture.

Comment: There is no need for moving parts to qualify as a "computer" . What's your real question?

Answer (score 1):

Fluid flows in the channels and steel balls and solenoids are used to block, or open, relevant channels.

Used in many automatic gearboxes, the balls can be solenoid controlled or spring loaded depending what needs to happen to control gear changes and a "soft" or "hard" aka "slow" or "fast" response.

Answer (score 0):

Fluid valves are regulated by pressure and velocity as the engine and transmission ratio along with acceleration and velocity of the vehicle, choose the optimal gear by torque and power available with engine RPM.

- considering an analog computer does the same with gears as impedance dividers and gain with voltage amplifiers and delays with RC values  it is a valid comparison.